# Way to tile numbered equations

Tags: equations, align, eqnarray

New to the LATEX and am not tempted at this at all. Honestly tried to find the solution for my task anywhere but, to the best of my understanding, there is no topic here which covers the solution of the like problem.

Problem itself is to find a way of tiling up the six numbered equations, numbers shall be on the left, grouped as 3 × 2, i. e.:

(1) equation1 (4) equation4

(2) equation2 (5) equation5

(3) equation3 (6) equation6.

Code for those equations1--6 is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\begin{document}
...
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial P}{\partial L} = \frac34 \frac{P}{L}\\
\frac{\partial P}{\partial C} = \frac14 \frac{P}{C}\\
\frac{L\partial P}{\partial L} = \frac34 P\\
\frac{C\partial P}{\partial C} = \frac14 P\\
\frac{\partial \, {\ln P}}{\partial \, {\ln L}} = \frac34\\
\frac{\partial \, {\ln P}}{\partial \, {\ln C}} = \frac14
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

Please can anyone help with this?

Thank very much in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TSX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can think of two solutions. First, you could place an `align` environment with all six equations in a two-column `multicols` environment. Second, you could place two separate `align` environments, each with three equations, in separate `minipage` environments of width `0.5\textwidth`.

Either way, you should specify the document class option `leqno` to tell LaTeX to place the equation numbers on the left.

If you don't need alignment on the `=` symbols, I suggest you use `gather` rather than `align` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}  % equation numbers on left
\usepackage{amsmath}   % for 'align' env.
\allowdisplaybreaks    % allow column breaks and page breaks
\usepackage{multicol}  % for 'multicols' env.

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial P}{\partial L} &= \frac34 \frac{P}{L}\\
\frac{\partial P}{\partial C} &= \frac14 \frac{P}{C}\\
\frac{L\,\partial P}{\partial L} &= \frac34 P \\
\frac{C\,\partial P}{\partial C} &= \frac14 P \\
\frac{\partial \ln P}{\partial \ln L} &= \frac34\\
\frac{\partial \ln P}{\partial \ln C} &= \frac14
\end{align}
\end{multicols}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial P}{\partial L}    &= \frac34 \frac{P}{L}\\
\frac{\partial P}{\partial C}    &= \frac14 \frac{P}{C}\\
\frac{L\,\partial P}{\partial L} &= \frac34 P
\end{align}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align}
\frac{C\,\partial P}{\partial C}      &= \frac14 P\\
\frac{\partial \ln P}{\partial \ln L} &= \frac34\\
\frac{\partial \ln P}{\partial \ln C} &= \frac14
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, nice! Thanks!